# How to select Sum data with SQL in Excel for distinct values?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, distinct

With this SQL code I want to take sum of net amounts by every item number separately:

```
myquery = "SELECT  distinct " & ItemNo & ", -SUM( " & NetAmount & " )   FROM " & table_TSE & _
    " WHERE " & ItemNo & " IN " & Itemnr1 & _
" AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & "'"
```

But I got error:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "GROUP BY" and "HAVING" clause at the end instead of "WHERE" when using aggregate functions like "SUM".

Within the "GROUP BY" clause you state the columns in which are not inside of a "SUM" function.

Then think of "HAVING" as a "WHERE" clause.

I haven't tested but this should work:

```
myquery = "SELECT  DISTINCT" & ItemNo & ", -SUM( " & NetAmount & " )  FROM " & table_TSE & _
    " GROUP BY [Date]," & ItemNo & " HAVING " & ItemNo & " IN " & Itemnr1 & _
" AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & "'"
```

Let me know if this helps!

Here is a good source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Now getting error: Column Trans_sales entry.Date is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either and aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try adding "[Date]" into the the "GROUP BY" clause

Comment: If I add dates it's working, but I I got for example 3 different lines with same Item number, But I need to get one line for each item number with sum all amounts for that item

Comment: You may have to remove "DISTINCT". Have you got an example of output?

Comment: Output is like this:                                                                                                       
    10472061 18,16528
    10472061 37,98528
    10472061 48,71792
    10472061 56,16
    20262878 82,64
    20262878 213,22314
    20262878 426,45

Comment: First is Item no, second  is amount, same I get without distinct

Comment: myquery = "SELECT  DISTINCT" & ItemNo & ", -SUM( " & NetAmount & " )  FROM " & table_TSE & _
   "WHERE" & ItemNo & " IN " & Itemnr1 & _
" AND [Date] BETWEEN " & date_from & " AND " & date_to  & " GROUP BY " & ItemNo " & "'"

                   After some research it turns out you can have a WHERE clause before a Group by, I did not know this! let me know if this works... Every day is  a learning day!

Comment: I've never stored a procedure within a variable before... I've only ever really used SQL Server so this is interesting to me!

Comment: Got the same error as in first  post photo

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of the data that needs manipulating or is it confidential? Kind of want to test myself as nobody has got it yet!

Comment: SO I just tried this on my own Database and it worked
SELECT [Id Column], SUM([ColumnToSum]) 
FROM table
WHERE [Id Column] IN (Data list) AND 
Date BETWEEN x AND y
GROUP BY [Id Column]

Comment: It should work, but it is not. Getting same error, somehow it cannot recognize group by function if it's in the end of query, maybe need some specific syntax for it, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

SUM() is an aggregate function in SQL, and when used in a select statement with other non-aggregate columns, should be accompanied with a GROUP BY statement containing any non-aggregate columns.

Consider changing your query to include

`" GROUP BY " & ItemNo &`

Reference Example: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions#sum_function

Comment: i should also point out that the 'GROUP BY' will also make your results unique, as all records of that item number will be grouped into a single line.

Comment: myquery = "SELECT  distinct " & ItemNo & ", -SUM( " & NetAmount & " )   FROM " & table_TSE & _
        " WHERE " & ItemNo & " IN " & Itemnr1 & _
    " AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & _
    "GROUP BY " & ItemNo & "'"

Comment: This query still got same error as before